# I dont understand the last step. I’m trying to understand how equation 10 follows, especially the last delta equation

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, dirac-delta, statistical-mechanics, liouville-function

I dont understand following steps of a solution where I need to find the Normalization constant $A(E,P,N)$ .
The normalization is given by:
$$
\int \rho(\vec x)d\vec x = 1
$$
where $d \vec x = C_N d^Np d^Nq$ and $C_N = \frac{1}{N!} \frac{1}{(2 \pi \hbar)^N}$

Constant energy E and constant momentum is given by:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i^2}{2m} = E \qquad   \sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i = P
$$
The microcanonical equilibrium density is:
$$
\rho (\vec x) = A(E,P,N) \space \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i^2}{2m}-E) \space \delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i - P)
$$
With $d^Npd^Nq = \prod_{i=1}^{N}dp_i dq_i$ the normalization factor is given by:

$$
1 = A C_N \int \prod_{i=1}^{N}dp_i dq_i \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{p_i^2}{2m}-E) \space \delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} p_i - P) \\ 
= A C_N V^N \int \prod_{i=1}^{N}d\tilde p_i \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{N} \frac{\tilde p_i^2}{2m}-\tilde E) \space \delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} \tilde p_i)\\
= A C_N V^N (2m)^\frac{N}{2} \tilde E^{\frac{N}{2}-1} \int \prod_{i=1}^{N}dz_i \delta(\sum_{i=1}^{N} z_i^2-1) \space \delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} z_i)\\
$$

where

$$
\tilde p_i = p_i - \frac{P}{N}, \quad \tilde E = E - \frac{P}{2mN} > 0, \quad z_i = \frac{\tilde p_i}{\sqrt{2m \tilde E}}
$$

I dont understant the last delta function $\delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} z_i)$. It should be $\delta (\sum_{i=1}^{N} \sqrt{2m \tilde E} \space z_i)$ , no?

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Also please provide some context to the question (i.e. the rest of the calculation and what the symbols mean). It should also be [completely in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange) and not in German.

Comment: @VincentBatens: I definitely agree with your first sentence. The second one is not the policy on this site; please see [What is Math SE's policy on posts in languages other than English?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35656), and also older posts [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23036) and [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19292).

Comment: What's the context? Where did you find these questions?

Comment: You can get properly sized parentheses (and other paired delimiters) that adapt to the size of their content by preceding them with `\left` and `\right`.

Answer (score 0):

You’re right; this is wrong.

The substitution of the $z_i$ for the $\tilde p_i$ as integration variables yields a factor $(2m\tilde E)^{\frac N2}$. The first delta function is $\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\frac{\tilde p_i^2}{2m}-\tilde E\right)=\delta\left(\tilde E\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i^2-1\right)\right)$, so replacing it by $\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i^2-1\right)$ yields a factor $\tilde E^{-1}$. The second delta function is $\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^N\tilde p_i\right)=\delta\left(\sqrt{2m\tilde E}\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i\right)$, so replacing it by $\delta\left(\sum_{i=1}^Nz_i\right)$ should have yielded another factor $\left(\sqrt{2m\tilde E}\right)^{-1}$, but the factors $(2m)^\frac N2\tilde E^{\frac N2-1}$ before the integral don’t reflect this last factor. Well spotted.